# ImageView with rounded corners in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, imageview, rounded-corners

I want to have an ImageView with rounded corners in my Fragment.
I've got the following Kotlin code:

```
val imageView: ImageView = root.findViewById(R.id.profile_view)
val pv = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(res, src)
pv.setCornerRadius = 0f
imageView.setImageDrawable(pv)
```

create and res are red underlined by Android Stuido.
create says:

> None of the following functions can be called with the following
>   arguments supplied:
>   - Bitmap?
>   - InputStream
>   - String

res says:

> Expression expected, but a package name found.

I hope somebody can help me to fix that problem.

Regards, Jeremy

Comment: Please check [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459916/how-to-make-an-imageview-with-rounded-corners]. I think with this, your issues will be resolved

Comment: Not really. I would be happy about a Kotlin solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this

```
package com.alok.myapplication

import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.widget.ImageView
import androidx.core.graphics.drawable.RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory


class RoundedImageView : ImageView {

constructor(context: Context) : super(context)

constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs)

constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(
    context,
    attrs,
    defStyleAttr
)

override fun setImageDrawable(drawable: Drawable?) {
    super.setImageDrawable(drawable)
    val radius = 0.1f
    val bitmap = (drawable as BitmapDrawable).bitmap
    val resourceId = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(resources, bitmap)
    resourceId.cornerRadius = bitmap.width * radius
    super.setImageDrawable(resourceId)
}
}
```

and add this imageview in your layout

```
 <com.alok.myapplication.RoundedImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/item_2"/>
```

I hope it will resolve your issue

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it using the Glide library.

```
Glide.with(imageView.context)
            .load(pictureUri)
            .apply(
                RequestOptions()
                    .transform(RoundedCorners(25))
            .into(imageView)
```