# I want to add rounded corners to my custom imageview in kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, imageview

I want to add rounded corners to my custom imageview in kotlin and has created the drawable resource file ready and not working and not able to find out the way to use the view.SetToOutline.plz help me out to have the rounded corners

**kotlin code**

```
import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.View
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView

class DynamicHeightImageView : AppCompatImageView {
    private var whRatio = 0f

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs)

    fun setRatio(ratio: Float) {
        whRatio = ratio
    }

    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
        if (whRatio != 0f) {
            val width = measuredWidth
            val height = (whRatio * width).toInt()
            setMeasuredDimension(width, height)
        }
    }

}
```

**xml file**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.georgcantor.wallpaperapp.util.DynamicHeightImageView
            android:id="@+id/pictureImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/image_item"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**drawable file**

````
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="10dp" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/off_white" />

    <solid android:color="@color/colorDetailPrimaryDark" />

</shape>```
````

Comment: Do you want full circle?

Comment: Actually like Pinterest!!!only curve corners

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58033719/12152049.               Can u help me in coding like this ...... It is similar to my problem but it is not working to my file...app Crashes by adding the last function my app fetches images from internet

Answer (score 0):

Please don't reinvent the wheel.There is a pretty library out there..https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView

you can make use of this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58033719/12152049.               Can u help me in coding like this ...... It is similar to my problem but it is not working to my file

Answer (score 0):

Also you can do it with Glide image loader library

```
fun loadImage (imageUrl:String, myImageView:ImageView) {
   val options:RequestOptions = RequestOptions().transform(RoundedCorners(10))
   Glide.with(context)
    .load(imageUrl)
    .apply(requestOptions)
    .into(myImageView)
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58033719/12152049.               Can u help me in coding like this ...... It is similar to my problem but it is not working to my file